# How can I make a turtle point towards a set of coordinates?

Tags: python, geometry, coordinates, turtle-graphics, angle

I am working on a program that draws a space filling curve. To do this, the turtle must be positioned at the start position and point towards the end position.

I have tried using turtle.setheading(turtle.towards(x,y)) but that resulted in the turtle pointing in the wrong direction.
I think it may have something to do with North in setheading being 90 instead of 0.
Help?

Comment: Or maybe you misunderstood how the axes for coordinates are oriented?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Community members may find it easier to help you if you provide the portion of your code that you believe is causing the problem.

Comment: It's unclear. Your code ```turtle.setheading(turtle.towards(x,y))``` should work fine. Test with ```turtle.goto(x, y)```.

Answer (score 0):

Use `turtle.mode('logo')` to make North as 0 degrees and positive angles clockwise. This should solve the issue and you can now use `turtle.setheading(turtle.towards(x,y))`.